# What is the correct way to check url type value?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I've a simple component like this one:

**SimpleComponent.qml**

```
Image {
 id: root

 property url selectedImage: ""
 property bool selected: false

 states: State {
   name: 'selected'
   when: selectedImage !== "" && selected

   PropertyChanges { target: root; source: selectedImage; }
 }
}
```

If I try to do something like the following, the image source will be replaced by `selectedImage` even if the condition should not be `true`.

**SimpleImplementation.qml**

```
Item {
 id: root

 SimpleComponent {
  id: simpleSwitchImage

  source: "/path/to/image.png"
  selected: true
 }
}
```

Attaching the following to `Component.onCompleted` I've got the commented results:

```
console.log(
    selectedImage,                        // empty string
    selectedImage === "",                 // false
    selectedImage === undefined,          // false
    selectedImage === null,               // false
    selectedImage === Qt.resolvedUrl(""), // false
    selectedImage.toString(),             // empty string
    selectedImage.toString() === "",      // true
    selectedImage.isEmpty,                // undefined
    selectedImage.empty                   // undefined
)
```

[According to the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-url.html) the only `true` I've got is the absolute path to the resource, is this the correct way to do such a simple check for an empty property of type `url`?

Comment: I can't test it right now but isn't there a `isEmpty` or `empty` property like [QUrl::isEmpty()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#isEmpty)? Sadly the QML doc is not so generous when it comes to basic QML types.

Comment: @xander You mean something like `typeof selectedImage === "undefined"`? I have not tried it in this case. I'm also not aware of something like `isEmpty` as I cannot find information about it (yet).

Comment: No I just mean as a bool property of url, like `selectedImage.isEmpty` or `selectedImage.empty`, can you try to log that? See the Qt doc of QUrl I've linked above, but as mentioned there is no documentation for QML url, at least not about properties/functions in any way. Since your `selectedImage` is of type url and not a simple string.

Comment: Sadly they both return `undefined`, I've updated the question with this new information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `SimpleComponent.qml` example code you are using strict inequality comparison between url QML type and zero length JavaScript string which is wrong:

```
when: selectedImage !== "" && selected
```

You could use *url* QML type's `toString()` method to get the url contents as a string

```
when: selectedImage.toString() !== "" && selected
```

or use JavaScript string's `length` property for checking:

```
when: selectedImage.toString().length>0 && selected
```

More specific answer:
I don't think there is any better way to check the "emptyness" of the url QML type.

Comment: How this is better than strict checking for `""`?

Comment: I read your question more carefully and noticed that you were actually asking more specifically. I don't think it was a good idea to provide example code which was already faulty and then wonder why it's not working "If I try to do something..." Anyway, I edited my answer and updated more specific answer too.

Comment: So this is the only way to do it?

Comment: I would say so. The url QML basic type doesn't provide any function for such checking so converting it to a string seems to be the only option at the moment. In the comment field of the open bug "Return local file path from url QML type" (http://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54988) you can see suggestion of "Url" type that provides similar API to QUrl, whilst the "url" value type stays as is. QUrl::isEmpty() would be the function in the C++ side. However, the status of the bug is unresolved.

Comment: Oh boy, I feel so silly. I've trying to so a basic string comparison on a url for 30 minutes. Where in the fine documentation did you find `toString()`? I can only see `URL()`, which *converts* to a Javascript `URL`, which has a `toString()`. But it turns out `toString()` can be called directly and all is well.